# Return Value 0, 1 or 2 if user has specific roles in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a C# Program where the User logs in via LinQConnect.

I now need a SQLQuery that return 0, 1 or 2.

```
select rolname 
from pg_user a
join pg_auth_members b on (a.usesysid=b.member)
join pg_roles c on (c.oid=b.roleid)
where
a.usename='USERNAME'
```

If User is in Role "RoleA" I want to return 1, if User is in Role "RoleB" I want to return 2, If he's in both, I Want to retrun 2 anyway, and if the User is in neither of the Roles, i want to return 0.

I know I can just check the Returned Roles in Code and then return the specific number, but can I get 0, 1 or 2 returned by the Query?

**EDIT:**

I added:

```
max(case when rolname = 'RoleA' then '1'
     when rolname = 'RoleB' then '2'
     else '0'
end)   // added max(), now it returns only 2 if im in both Roles
```

Comment: A CASE statement should work

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: @MartinCook, you mean a `case` _expression_.

Comment: @jarlh good catch. Lots of the internet gets that distinction wrong...

Comment: use MAX(CASE WHEN rolename = 'A' ... WHEN rolename = 'B' ...)

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Thanks!

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work -

```
    MAX(CASE WHEN rolname = 'RoleA' THEN '1'
             WHEN rolname = 'RoleB' THEN '2'
             WHEN COUNT(rolname) = 2 THEN '2'
             ELSE '0'
         END)
```

Though i have not tried it yet but i think it should work.